# Trying to open some links with an inline modal popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am new here so bare me with some time. I want to open some of the links in my page with an inline popup window.

I guess that those special links have to have a different id attribute that triggers the jquery script
I used the script from this page sohtanaka.com/web-design/inline-modal-window-w-css-and-jquery/ that has a simple code with great result

The problem is that this script shows the content of the div and am trying to show the page of the link

Thank you very much for your help and info.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not trying to show inline content, but just a normal modal with an iframe or ajax. You would probably be better served using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).

Fancybox has good documentation and should be easier for you to set up.